# Accesing Windows on Parallels Desktop from external device

Tags: macos, ip, parallels

I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Parallels Desktop 7 with Windows 7 on it. On Windows I'm developing a server (IIS) running on localhost. Subnet ip of windows is 10.211.55.3, and server can be accessed from browser on Mac. But I also want to access my server from external device (in my case, from android phone). Is it possible? What should I do for that?

In VM preferences I've selected Shared Network.

Comment: Switch to Bridged Network. See http://whiletruecode.com/post/hosting-an-aspnet-site-in-iis-express-using-parallels-on-mac-osx